# plotting categorical data pandas/bokeh

Tags: pandas, bokeh

I have a pandas dataframe which gives the number of pass and fail students in every subject. I want to generate a plot which gives pass and fail for every subject. I tried groupby method but i can get a plot for a single one. I want a plot which has subject names as x-axis and no. of pass and fails in y-axis. Here is the sample dataframe.

```
10IS665 10ISL67 10ISL68
F        F        P
F        F        P
P        P        F
p        P        P
p        P        P
p        F        F
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create some test data first:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 4) > 0.3, columns=list("ABCD"))
df = df.replace([True, False], ["P", "F"])
```

`apply()` `value_count()` to every column of the data, and transpose the result:

```
df_count = df.apply(pd.value_counts).T
```

Then call `plot()` with `kind="bar"`:

```
df_count.plot(kind="bar")
```

output:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can you please explain a little how this is working?

Comment: ok. so the apply function applies the value count for every column. Thanks a lot!